# On a cricket ground, What is the blackboard situated at every straight boundary for?

Tags: cricket

On a cricket ground, what is the blackboard situated at every straight boundary used for?

Sometimes the batsmen order this blackboard to be moved.

Answer (score 6):

The sight screen is placed behind the bowler so that the batsman can pick up the ball as soon as possible. It is black for ODIs as the ball is white, but White for Test Matches as the ball is red.

There have been length delays as the sight screen can break and moving spectators can throw a batman off.

Answer (score 0):

**Sightscreen**

[Wikitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sightscreen)

> A large screen, at each end of a cricket field, coloured to provide visual contrast to the cricket ball, to aid the batsman in seeing its movement through the air.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_clothing_and_equipment)

> A screen placed at the boundary known as the sight screen. This is aligned exactly parallel to the width of the pitch and behind both pairs of wickets.

---

Other info :

- White in Test Matches - Red ball.
- Black in ODI/T20 Matches - White ball.